# How do I make it so that the countdown shows up on the tkinter window instead of in my cmd?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code basically allows the user to set a countdown(in seconds) and when the countdown get to zero a message appears. I’m a beginner in tkinter and python so I don’t exactly know how to make my countdown show up in the tkinter window because it only shows up in the cmd.

```
import time
import tkinter as Alarm
class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="")
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.startTimer)
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="right")
    def countdown(k,q):
        j=q
        k=0
        while True:
            if(j>=0):
                print(str(j),end="\r")
            time.sleep(1)
            j-=1
            if(j==-1):
                break
        if(j==-1):
            print("Alarm!", end="\r")
            time.sleep(1)
    def startTimer(self):
        try:
            i = int(self.entry.get())
            self.countdown(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter whole digits only in all boxes")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Alarm.Tk()
    test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use after(delay, callback=None) once the timer is started and then keep calling the function with a one second delay until the timer has reached zero. Then use a message box to display your message. To show the countdown, just have an updating entry or similar GUI object that updates every time the function is called.  https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22870/-after--

Comment: Perhaps `print` is not the right function?

Comment: Ok I’ll try that

Comment: I don’t really know what else to use tbh.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show some animation, `after()` is the way to go. Don't use `time.sleep()` as it will freeze your `mainloop`.

```
import tkinter as Alarm

class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="Start")
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.startTimer)
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="right")

    def countdown(self, s):
        if s==0:
            self.output.configure(text="Alarm!")
            return  
        self.output.configure(text=str(s))
        s -= 1
        self.output.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(s))

    def startTimer(self):
        try:
            i = int(self.entry.get())
            self.countdown(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter whole digits only in all boxes")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Alarm.Tk()
    test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid `sleep` because it stops the process and you won't be able to see the "animation".

> .after(delay, callback=None) is a method defined for all tkinter widgets. This method simply calls the function callback after the given delay in ms.

[Read more](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22870/-after--)
It counts down from x seconds and when it hits 0, a message box appears on screen.

[image]

```
import time
import tkinter as Alarm
from tkinter import messagebox

class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="")
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.startTimer)
        self.secondsLabel = Alarm.Label(self, text="")

        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="right")
        self.secondsLabel.pack(side="left", fill="x")

        self.seconds = 0

    def countdown(self):

        if self.seconds > 0:
            self.seconds -= 1
            self.secondsLabel.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown())
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("DONE")

        self.secondsLabel.configure(text="%i s" % self.seconds)


    def startTimer(self):
        try:
            time = int(self.entry.get())
            self.seconds = time
            self.countdown()
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter whole digits only in all boxes")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Alarm.Tk()
    test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see, I just recently got into python and tkinter so I didn’t really know how to properly use sleep() and after(), but now I understand it a bit.